# When do I need to re-compile Jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReporting engine, and i need to optimize reporting performance. Currently my application compiles reports from *.jrxml files every time, as I'm not changing the reports now and app is not able to generate user-defined reports I should compile them once and use .jasper files in future..... AM I RIGHT?? And do I need to re-compile them?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your application check both the .jrxml file and the .jasper file; if the later is missing or older than the .jrxml, recompile, otherwise just use the .jasper file.

Comment: if you are using a build tool like maven or ant it is possible to integrate this step in the build lifecycle. for maven there is an excelent plugin on codehaus

Answer (score 0):

You must not recompile your reports if you don't change them. Actually, there are two regular scenarios:

- reports created by iReport - in that case compile them in iReport and use the compiled form
- reports are generated on the fly, dynamically - in that case you'll need to compile them everytime. This is a much rarer case, though.